# Why am I getting "TypeError: onSelect is not a function."?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am passing data from a child component to its parent via a prop which is assigned to a button.

Code below:

**Parent component**

```
const Parent:React.FC<Props> = (props) =>{
return (
<View> 
     <LocationPicker
         onSelect={(e,region)=>handleConfirm(region)} />    
      </View>
    )
}
```

**Child component:**

```
interface LocationPickerProps {
  onSelect:(event:GestureResponderEvent,region: Region)=>void;
}
export const LocationPicker: React.FC<LocationPickerProps> = ({onSelect}) => {
    const region:Region = {...} 
 return(
    <LargeButton onPress={(e)=>onSelect(e,region)}>SELECT LOCATION</LargeButton>
    )
}
```

The error I get is  `TypeError: onSelect is not a function. (In 'onSelect(e, region)', 'onSelect' is undefined)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `React.FC<Props>`  Props?, did you mean -> `LocationPickerProps`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out,  I was just using nameless variables for this code snippet but I overlooked some of it. I've updated the code.

Comment: The error message says that `onSelect` is `undefined` so something must be going wrong and not connecting `onSelect={(e,region)=>handleConfirm(region)}` to it. It looks like you've produced a [mcve] which doesn't actually reproduce the problem. Maybe your real code has a type in a name somewhere.

Comment: Here is the working example of your code, not sure why are you getting `undefined` 
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-goldberg-3kg5c7